# commented querys are getting executed

Tags: php, mysql

i just noticed in my mysql slow log that even query which i have commented and not using  anymore due to heavy load on server due to those query are still getting executed.i cant believe that commented query will get executed

i have this mysql query which i had used in past

```
    //$query="SELECT * FROM tableA where col='p' order by rand() LIMIT 3";
```

the tableA is having 20 million data so you can imagine what will be the condition with rand() so i removed but again and again mysql slow log will throw this query taken 45 seconds etc .

As far as i know commented php & mysql query are not executed but in my case it is executing i have same code in only one place and i checked by deleting the code and in that case slow log will not log that delay if i again add that query and comment it will start coming in slow log

Comment: Please copy paste the php code where you commented out this (including the code lines before and after it.) We can't guess what your code looks like.

Comment: @GrantThomas check updated questions

Comment: @nos  check updated questions

Comment: That line isn't executing anything, and it isn't commented out. You'll need to post the entire section of your code

Comment: @nos i have commented but seems moderator has removed the //

Comment: @Pekka웃   entire code //  $query="SELECT * FROM tableA where col='p' order by rand() LIMIT 3";

Comment: @echo_me please do not remove characters from problem code.

Comment: Please show more code. Where is the query made?

Comment: @Pekka웃 see the revised code its more than sufficient this code is only executing

Comment: Where are you executing the query? The code you show is only setting the `$query` variable. It's not executing the query. That must be happening elsewhere.

Comment: @crypticツ its just because we dont see good the code ,i thought its not with the code.sorry

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, make sure you are commenting within the `<?php ?>` tags

```
<?php

    //$query="SELECT * FROM tableA where col='p' order by rand() LIMIT 3";

?>
```

or something like this:

```
<?php

    /*
     *
     *$query="SELECT * FROM tableA where col='p' order by rand() LIMIT 3";
     *
     */

?>
```

If, after this, the code is still getting executed, it means the error is not in this line of code. Perhaps there are similar lines somewhere else, or the new code is replicating the same mistake.

Comment: that complete page is in php

Comment: you mean all page has the php tags even if it is a .php file?
Check my edit in the answer...